# How conda manages the environment with system python and python installed with this

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I have installed anconda with python 3.5, but i am curious to know how conda is managing between system python(2.7.6) and python3.5(installed with anaconda).
Particularly If I make a new environment with conda help containing python 3.5 and don't switch to my root env in conda while restarting the system. Does system start with python3 as default or python 2.7.6?

I am in need of answer to this as one of my friend installed Anaconda with python3.5 as default to system which broke the system dependencies and It did not start.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

if you already used pip and virtual env, conda is like both at the same time. It's a package manager and also creates virtual environments. 
To answer your question, conda creates a new environement, exporting python paths for this environment and installing all packages here. You can always switch between environments, but after reboot, all your virtual environments would be desactivated and you'll have your default system python path (2.7).

Comment: I have some doubts, does conda starts by itself when system boots, how terminal differentiate between python from conda and system python. Is there a way to justify the above or know(any source) for ''all your virtual environments would be desactivated and you'll have your default system python path (2.7)'' ... Thanks

Comment: OK, when your system reboot it loads your config files in .bashrc or .profile (depends on system), that's how you get your default system env. What conda does when you do source activate, it loads current env to your configs, changing python paths.

Comment: Look here for conda command and some explications http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html